# Spring Integration MappingMongoConverter write a list

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-integration

Hi I am new to Spring Integration and I was wondering if anyone knew how to work around an issue i am having. When I setup the mongo outbound-channel-adapter, I am receiving a list of objects in the custom MappingMongoConverter write method. Does anyone know how to write these to Mongo as individual documents? At the moment I can store them all in one document, but would prefer one document per object in the list.

Many thanks,
Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a `<splitter/>` upstream of the outbound channel adapter (it only needs an input channel and output channel - the default splitter will split a `Collection` into its individual elements).